# Is triaxial carbon fiber gimmick?

Tags: carbon-fiber

Is there any benefit to using triaxial weave pattern instead of common twill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a gimmick. Triaxial weaving has been around for a long time, and can be seen in baskets, hats, etc. etc. It often exhibits superior structural properties such as greater resistance to shear forces, tearing, bursting etc. The sheet will also be generally more isotropic, so if you don't know which direction your forces will be coming from, it may be a better choice.

Whether there is any *benefit*, however, depends entirely on the specific application. You may not need any of the above properties, making the increased cost not worth it. Further, if you are exclusively loading the fibres in one orientation, then a square weave might be a better choice. What has prompted this question?

Comment: I saw this weave patern,I found some claims on internet about its superiority but became sceptical becose it seemed vast majority of carbon fiber prepregs are twill.Carbon fiber and its fake immitations are extensively used as decoration,I was thinking this weave is just attention grabber with no real benefit.

Comment: You're right to be wary, as some weaves provide no mechanical improvement, and purely aesthetic changes [(e.g. this one)](http://www.cristex.co.uk/uploads/certification/Alutex%20V%20610%20RH%20(1).jpg) That said, if looks are your primary aim, there *is a benefit* in choosing one of the aesthetic weaves!